# Postback during an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my page have an ajax call using jquery :

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/myMethod",
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg)
    {
      alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(e, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
       alert("Error");
    },
    complete: function(s, e)
    {
        alert("it is done");
    }

}
```

Everything works fine, except when the user refreshes the page (or causes a Postback) while the Ajax call is sent (but not returned yet) it automatically goes into the "error:" method.

Is there any way to avoid that?  I don't want to show the "Error" message to my user if he just refreshed the page during the ajax call.

Thanks

Comment: Can you just ignore it based on error code or something?

Comment: or possibly.... make the error callback less obvious? it's going to happen regardless.

Comment: What is triggering your AJAX call? Please post all of your code.

Comment: No I cannot ignore the error, the webService may have a problem and I want to notify the user using an alert (It needs to be obvious). The ajax call is just triggered on the ValueModified client event of a DevExpress spinEdit (which is basically an html input at the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recreated your problem, but only in Chrome; it works fine in Internet Explorer 10.

Thinking it was a cached request issue, I tried setting `cache: false` in the jQuery `.ajax()` settings, but to no avail.

Handling the particular error returned seems to work, although it is not a very elegant solution:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/myMethod",
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(e, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if (e.status === 0) {
            alert("Error status 0.");
        } 
        else {
            alert("Error");
        }
    },
    complete: function(s, e){
        alert("it is done");
    }
}
```

Note: You will most likely want to just ignore the error status 0, so I would remove the `alert("Error status 0.");`, but I left it in there for debugging purposes.

UPDATE:

You can trap other status codes, such as:

```
else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
    alert("Requested page not found. [HTTP 404]");
} 
else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
    alert("Internal Server Error [HTTP 500].");
}
else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
    alert("Requested JSON parse failed.");
} 
else if (exception === 'timeout') {
    alert("Time out error.");
} 
else if (exception === 'abort') {
    alert("AJAX request aborted.');
}
```

Comment: I like this approach!  But just wonder if any other kind of error could return e.status === 0. :/